# Struts 2.3 simple action error - beginner level

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, http-status-code-404

I am getting the following error while try to connect to my local server.

I am accessing my page  as below...
http://localhost:8080/MyFirstStruts/HomeScreen.action

> HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [HomeScreen] associated with context path [/MyFirstStruts].

My Project name is MyFirstStruts.

***HomeScreen.Java   code***

```java
package com.cmdb.actions;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class HomeScreen extends ActionSupport {

/**
 * The action method
 * @return name of view
 */
public String execute() {

    return SUCCESS;
}


} //end of class 
 // end of class
```

***web.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>MyFirstStruts</display-name>


  <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
      </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**struts.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="HomeScreen" class="actions.HomeScreen"
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/Home.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: What's the location of `struts.xml`?

Comment: Struts.xml is inside the Web-INF folder.  web.xml and Struts.xml are in the same folder.

Comment: It should be on classpath or otherwise you should change init parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The class path of the action you mentioned in struts.xml `actions.HomeScreen` is not same as your class package `com.cmdb.actions` These must be the same.

Comment: Thanks Alireza for your help. Even after changing the class package, it is not working.

Comment: <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="HomeScreen" class="com.cmdb.actions.HomeScreen"
            method="execute"> ---> Pls. see the new class path.

Answer (score 0):

The `struts.xml` file must be under the `../WEB-INF/classes` folder, which you have to create manually and move your `struts.xml` file to it.

Your `/WEB-INF` folder tree should look something like the following:

> ../WEB-INF
>   ../WEB-INF/classes
>   ../WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml
>   ../WEB-INF/web.xml

Also, as @Alireza mentionned, you should set your `class` attribute in `struts.xml` as following `class="com.cmdb.actions.HomeScreen"`

This will get you up and running.